# How to continue looping a list without wait for new messages telethon python

Tags: python, for-loop, telegram, telethon

I'm new with telethon and I have a telethon python script that is listening for telegram messages, all this part works correctly, but I'm improving my script, what I need to achieve is the following:

I'm looping a list, that needs to do something that takes around 10-15 seconds for each item in the list, If I do this right after the message arrives, I lost those 10-15 seconds, hence I decided to change my code but I'm facing an issue that next item is not iterated as telethon is waiting now for the next message to arrive hence the code starts failing, I'm new with async functions and probably is something easy but I can't get it, please see my code example below:

Working code:

```
client = TelegramClient('session', API_ID, API_HASH)
@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=chatId))
async def my_event_handler(event):
        text = event.raw_text
        for item in items:
            # do something, it works fine, but I need to have other stuff ready
            # before telegram message arrives 

client.start()
client.run_until_disconnected()
```

Looking for something like this?

```
for item in items:
    # do something before a new message arrives

client = TelegramClient('session', API_ID, API_HASH)
@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=chatId))
async def my_event_handler(event):
        text = event.raw_text
        # do all the stuff that I need to do right after message is arrived
        await client.disconnect()

client.start()
client.run_until_disconnected()
```

The issue with code above is that once client is disconnected it finishes the code, but I'm looking to continue with the next iteration

Comment: You probably want to use `asyncio.gather()` for multiple coroutines. However, if the list gets longer (because each task takes 15 seconds), the could be a long que or other downstream issues.

Comment: The queue is filled with 4 or 5 messages every 10 or 20 minutes, so I'm not too worried about the list